# Restlet extractor returns attributes as nulls

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

I am trying to extract the url query parmeters without success.

eg., AboutWebServices/merchantofferings?lat=5?long=7?cat=9

Using a Tomcat server, I've tried various orders for the Restlets:

```
@Override
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {

     Router router = new Router(getContext());

    Extractor extractor = new Extractor(getContext());
    extractor.extractFromQuery("lat", "lat", true); 
    extractor.extractFromQuery("long", "long", false);
    extractor.extractFromQuery("cat", "cat", false);

    ChallengeAuthenticator guard = new ChallengeAuthenticator(getContext(),    
      ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, 
            "AnywhereAbout");
    guard.setVerifier(new UserVerifer());

    guard.setNext(extractor);
    extractor.setNext(router);

   //     router.attach("/merchantofferings", extractor);
    router.attach("/merchantofferings", MerchantOfferings.class);

    router.attach("/merchantofferings/{id}", MerchantOfferings.class);


    router.attach("/merchantprofile", MerchantProfile.class);

    router.attach("/merchantprofile/{id}", MerchantProfile.class);

    return guard;
   }
```

the routing works ok to this method but the attributes are null.

```
 //@Get("json+?lat?long?cat")
 @Get("json")
 public String representGet() {

Context context = getContext();

String lat = (String) context.getAttributes().get("lat");
String lon = (String) context.getAttributes().get("long");
String cat = (String) context.getAttributes().get("cat");

    return "hello, world: " + this.getRequest().toString();
 }
```

Also I've been reading the new Restlet in Action. Great book but while it says you can specify the query parameters in the annotation it doesn't explain how they would be used i.e., no examples. Does anyone know? In any case variations with the @Get("json+?lat?long?cat") didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure the URL is right? I am not expert with restlets, but in HTTP such a list of parameters would be `?lat=4&lon=10&...`

Comment: Thanks for that correction. Changed it to the following but got the same results.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/anywhereAboutWebServices/merchantofferings?lat=5&long=7&cat=9

Comment: reducing the code to handle just one parm and sending in merchantofferings?lat=5 also got a null

Comment: The attributes are extracted into the "Request" attributes, not the Context ones.

Comment: Fantastic that worked thanks Jerome. Impressive Restlet product and Restlet In Action book, by the way, Jerome.